# How to deal with whitespace in the path of the root folder

Tags: php, whitespace

I wrote a PHP script on my local server which needs to include path for the file where I need to write contents to the file using `file_put_contents` which was working without any problem on the localhost. I moved the files to the webserver where it has been configured with the path which has spaces in between 
for ex:
C:\Program File (xxx)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\writtencode\writefile\

When I try to open the folder writefile to write the contents to temp_1.cfg file in that folder it pops up  the error

> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(C:\ProgramFile(xxx)\ApacheSoftwareFoundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\writtencode\writefile\temp_1.cgf)
>   [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in C:\Program File (xxx)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\writtencode\writefile\index.php

Any idea how to remove or tackle with the problem of spaces in the path when writing contents to the file using `file_put_contents`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried enclosing the path in quote marks?
Also you may need to escape all  backslashes so:

`file_put_content(C:\ProgramFile(xxx)\ApacheSoftwareFoundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\writtencode\writefile\temp_1.cgf);`

becomes:

`file_put_content('C:\\ProgramFile(xxx)\\ApacheSoftwareFoundation\\Apache2.2\\htdocs\\writtencode\\writefile\\temp_1.cgf');`

Comment: I have enclosed the path in quote marks and I need to include the whitespaces in the path so that it takes the whitespaces and writes it to the correct file

Comment: OK, for an easy fix I would add: `subst x: "C:\Program File (xxx)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\"` to a batch file (e.g. mapx.bat). Run this batch file and now your htdocs folder will be accessible through drive x:

`file_put_content('x:\writtencode\writefile\temp_1.cgf');`

Answer (score 5):

```
$path ="C:\ProgramFile(xxx)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\writtencode\writefile\temp_1.cgf";
file_put_contents($path = str_replace(' ', '\ ', $path));
```